# How to upload file from frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query, express-fileupload

I am developing a full stack web-app as part of my thesis. One of the things I am supposed to implement is the ability to send csv files from the front end to the back end. I chose to work with Express and React and I am implementing them on TypeScript. I am using the express-fileupload module to manage the files on the Express App and axios to send http requests. I have wrote Unit Tests for the file function on the back end and it works just fine, so the problem lies on the front end.

This is the function that is supposed to send the files:

```js
async function uploadDatasetFile(formData: FormData): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/files/upload",
      formData,
      {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw error.response.data;
  }
}
```

This is the query that calls the uploadDatasetFile function:

```js
  const fileMutation = useMutation(uploadDatasetFile);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<DatasetFormValues> = dataset => {
    if (dataset.name && dataset.file) {
      console.log(dataset.file);
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", dataset.file);
      formData.append("name", dataset.name);
      fileMutation.mutate(formData);
    }
  };
```

Finally this is the back end code

```js
    this.app.route('/files/upload')
      .post(
        FilesMiddleware.validateUploadedFile,
        FilesMiddleware.validateRequiredPath,
        FilesController.uploadFile
      );
```

It doesn't pass the file check and it returns 400. What should I do?

Comment: When you log the dataset.file what is the output?

Comment: It's mentioned as ``FileList [ File ]``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataset.file` was a FileList actually and I had to change `onSubmit` to:

```js
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<DatasetFormValues> = dataset => {
    if (dataset.name && dataset.file) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", dataset.file[0]);
      formData.append("name", dataset.name);
      fileMutation.mutate(formData);
    }
  };
```